# Mail to PHP Seems to fail, but where?

Tags: php, postfix-mta

I have set up mail to an incoming address to forward in postfix to an alias for a php script. I think this is working because of the following entries in mail.log:

```
Oct 22 00:07:02 doodle postfix/qmgr[19688]: 60AB5688811C: from=<me@gmail.com>, size=1468, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 22 00:07:17 doodle postfix/local[26486]: 60AB5688811C: to=<php_mail_handler@localhost>, orig_to=<php@doodle.com>, relay=local, delay=16, delays=1.8/0.1/0/14, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command:  php /home/doodle/htdocs/mail_handler.php)
Oct 22 00:07:17 doodle postfix/qmgr[19688]: 60AB5688811C: removed
```

This seems to suggest that postfix is delivering it to the script. I get no error bounced back to my email, and yet the script does not execute (it should write the time to a file). The script works from the command line and from web execution. Its code is:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('php.txt','a+');

fwrite($f,date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."\n");
fclose($f);

?>
```

My aliases file contains:

```
php_mail_handler: "| php /home.doodle/htdocs/mail_handler.php"
```

My initial problem is that it is failing silently - mail.log, as can be seen above, seems to suggest all is well. Is there a log that would tell me why php fails to execute that I can check? Any idea with regard to the general problem? Vaguely similar posts in forums for sendmail seem to say that that requires symlinks in smrsh, but I have found nothing saying that postfix requires this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mat

Comment: Is this a Linux host running SELinux, by any chance?  If so, `grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log`

Comment: You may need to use the full path to php in your call to `php /home/doodle/htdocs/mail_handler.php` so it looks like `/usr/bin/php /home/doodle/htdocs/mail_handler.php`  The other thing to check would be that the php script and/or directory is readable by the user that executes the call.

Comment: It would seem not, Michael, I am afraid. audit.log doesn't exist for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisiting this years later, I have come across again and solved the same problem:

Postfix uses the unprivileged user "nobody" to execute piped commands from to aliases. To overcome this, create a user with the required privileges and assign to default_privs in main.cf (you will need to add the line):

default_privs = mynewuser

Restart and you are away.

Answer (score 1):

if Michaels solution won´t work, instead of using

```
$f = fopen('php.txt','a+');
fwrite($f,date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."\n");
```

try

```
system("echo 'it works!' > /home/yourname/php.txt");
```

On my fresh wheezy installation postfix's php CLI call was not able to access fopen and fwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Add a shebang to the top of the PHP script, make it executable, and remove the `php` from the pipe call. This avoids any problems postfix may have resolving the path to the PHP binary.

```
// Top of the PHP file...
#!/usr/bin/php -q

# Alias file:
php_mail_handler: "|/home/doodle/htdocs/mail_handler.php"

# make it executable
chmod +x /home/doodle/htdocs/mail_handler.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael - I tried the above, to no avail, I am afraid, but I did manage to get PHP CLI logging to syslog so, now I can see that it is a permission error problem with the third line, opening the file for writing. This is weird as both mail_handler.php and php.txt are set to 777 but at least it is something to go on. Thanks for your help.